# To delete dictionaries with duplicate values for keys in two dictionary lists

Tags: python

I want to remove a dictionary from the `l2` list that has duplicate values for the `["name"]` key in two dictionary lists.
How do I do this?

```py
l = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tom"
  }
]

l2 = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "gender": "male",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alex",
    "gender": "male"
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sofía",
    "gender": "female"
    "country": "Mexico"
  },
]
```

Results sought

```py
[
  {
    "name": "Alex",
    "gender": "male"
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sofía",
    "gender": "female"
    "country": "Mexico"
  },
]
```

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem yet? Can you show us your attempt and where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: Is it an exercise or a real problem ? As you would like to have an index on `name` key if you had to process a lot of entries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> [d for d in l2 if d["name"] not in [d1["name"] for d1 in l]]
[{'name': 'Alex', 'gender': 'male', 'country': 'Canada'},
 {'name': 'Sofía', 'gender': 'female', 'country': 'Mexico'}]
```

Comment: for efficiency, better make a set and avoid recreating the pool at every step: `S = {d1["name"] for d1 in l}`, then `[d for d in l2 if d["name"] not in S]`